# Map canvas covers other elements on Android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing an application on Android using PhoneGap and i want map to be 100% width and height of the screen. The problem is that all of DOM elements like divs are not displayed above my map when i'm running the app on android device. E.g. popups are triggered but they're under map canvas (setting high z-index doesn't help).

While running on browser (FF, Chrome) evrything works fine. Is it problem with Android default browser? Does anyone know how to solve this?

Example:

```
<a href="" data-role="button">button</a>
```

I can't make this simple JQM button display above the map.

Comment: Ok I don't know how it works, but I've included <script> tags in wrong order. Now it almost works i.e. popup shows up, but fades out immediately. I think i can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to be careful about order of including js/css files. So if you're writing an app using JQM, google-maps-api and phone gap you should remember:

First include css files e.g
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />`

Then this google api declaration 
`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>`

After that the jquery .js file 
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>`

Next jquery ui map files like 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>`

And at last jquery mobile script file (I think this is where I made mistake)

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>`